# How many binary relations can be defined on a set of $5$ elements?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let $X$ be a set with $5$ elements.

How many binary relations on $X$ are either reflexive or symmetric or both?

show work. you need not simplify the answer.

Comment: What was your attempt

Comment: @Sudeep  If X be a set with N elements,  then it's likely to have N reflexive & N(N-1)/2 symmetric binary relations. Total Binary relations being (N*N). Feel free to correct if am wrong.

Comment: All these are on the powers of $2$ @AlekhyaVemavarapu

Comment: can u please elaborate ? @MayankDeora

Comment: It's just like on or off for $N \times N$ pairs of elements that's how $2^{N \times N}$

Answer (score 1):

let a = the number of reflexive relations
let b = the number of symmetric relations
let c = the number of reflexive and symmetric relations

Our answer should be a+b-c. Now, how do we find a?
Out of $5^2=25$ pairs we must have the pairs in the (e,e) form where e is one of 5 elements. Remaining 20 pairs will yield up a number equal to $2^{20}$
Now, let's find b. 5 pairs are in the (e,e) form. Remaining 20 pairs are in the (e,f) form where e is different from f. For the relation to be symmetric if we have a pair (e,f) then we should also have (f,e). Therefore, we divide this number by 2, namely,  20/2=0. Ok, now we also need to take the first 5 pairs into consideration. 5+10 = 15  which gives us $2^{15}$
For c , we should have the 5 pairs in the (e,e) form. For the remaining 20 pairs, if we take (e,f) then we should also have (f,e) so we can think as if we need to choose one of 10 pairs of pairs. This gives us $2^{10}$
So, our answer is $2^{20}$+ $2^{15}$ - $2^{10}$